# Marker cluster number in a polygon or/and infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer, polygons

When you click on some polygon you got infowindow with the name of these polygon, is possible to put in this infowindow number of markers inside this polygon (same like marker cluster number) or to put this number (marker cluster number) on the polygon?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css" media="screen" />
    <title>StanOnline</title>

<style type="text/css">
html, body, #map_canvas {
width:   100%;
height:  100%;
margin:  0;
padding: 0;
} 
.infowindow * {font-size: 90%; margin: 0}
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js">
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
<!--Show / Hide div dmenu-->
 function toggle(id) {
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
        if (state == 'block') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    } 
</script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
var gmarkers = [];
function makeLink() {} ;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var geoXml = null;
var geoXmlDoc = null;
var map = null;
var myLatLng = null;
var myGeoXml3Zoom = true;
var sidebarHtml = "";
var infowindow = null;
var kmlLayer = null;
var preserveViewport = true;
var filename = "http://mini.hr/stanonline/mo_bck.kml";
var icon = new    google.maps.MarkerImage("http://localhost/projekt/7stanonline/img/punkt.gif",
new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
var currentPopup;

function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.extend(pt);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pt,
    icon: icon,
    //map: map
});

var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: info,
    maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    if (currentPopup != null) {
        currentPopup.close();
        currentPopup = null;
    }
    popup.open(map, marker);
    currentPopup = popup;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
    currentPopup = null;
});

gmarkers.push(marker);

 }



 function MapTypeId2UrlValue(maptype) {
   var urlValue = 'm';
   switch(maptype){
   case google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID:    urlValue='h';
                    break;
  case google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE: urlValue='k';
                    break;
  case google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN:   urlValue='t';
                    break;
  default:
  case google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP:   urlValue='m';
                    break;
}
return urlValue;
 }


function initialize() {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.345537,14.439621);
  // these set the initial center, zoom and maptype for the map 
  // if it is not specified in the query string
  var lat = 45.345537;
  var lng = 14.439621;
  var zoom = 13;
  var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;




  // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
  // looking something like  "?marker=3"

  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();

    // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "id") {id = unescape(value);}
    if (argname == "filename") {filename = unescape(value);}

    if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
    if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
    if (argname == "zoom") {
  zoom = parseInt(value);
  myGeoXml3Zoom = false;
}
    if (argname == "type") {
// from the v3 documentation 8/24/2010
// HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images. 
// ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map. 
// SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images. 
// TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation. 
      if (value == "m") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
      if (value == "k") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
      if (value == "h") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;}
      if (value == "t") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;}

    }
  }
  if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  }
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: zoom,
                center: myLatLng,
                // zoom: 5,
                // center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: maptype
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                  myOptions);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

 geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                infoWindow: infowindow,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
        zoom: myGeoXml3Zoom,

                afterParse: useTheData
            });

            geoXml.parse(filename);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", makeSidebar);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", makeSidebar);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", makeSidebar);
  // Make the link the first time when the page opens
  makeLink();

  // Make the link again whenever the map changes
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', makeLink);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', makeLink);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', makeLink);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', makeLink);
  //php addmarkers
    addMarker(45.374632, 14.425697,'<b>93 Feet East</b><br/>150 Brick Lane,  London  E1 6RU&lt;br/&gt;7 Dec 2010 : Jenny &amp; Johnny&lt;br/&gt;');
addMarker(45.374632, 14.425697,'<b>93 Feet East</b><br/>150 Brick Lane, London  E1 6RU&lt;br/&gt;7 Dec 2010 : Jenny &amp; Johnny&lt;br/&gt;');
addMarker(45.348674, 14.386749,'<b>Adelphi Theatre</b><br/>The Strand, London  WC2E 7NA&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Love Never Dies');
addMarker(45.35051, 14.351883,'<b>Adelphi Theatre</b><br/>The Strand, London  WC2E 7NA&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Love Never Dies');
addMarker(45.319618, 14.501915,'<b>Albany, The</b><br/>240 Gt. Portland Street, London  W1W 5QU');
addMarker(45.339893, 14.475479,'<b>Aldwych Theatre</b><br/>Aldwych, London  WC2B 4DF&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Dirty Dancing');
addMarker(45.343513, 14.436684,'<b>Alexandra Palace</b><br/>Wood Green, London  N22&lt;br/&gt;30 Oct 2010 : Lynx All-Nighter');
addMarker(45.330736, 14.434211,'<b>Stan F.La Guardia 10</b><br/>Najbolji stan na svijetu');
addMarker(45.385431, 14.357071,'<b>sdas</b><br/>dfsada');

  };

function kmlPgClick(pm) {
if (geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[pm].polygon.getMap()) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon,"click");
} else {
  geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon,"click");
}
}
function kmlPlClick(pm) {
if (geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[pm].polyline.getMap()) {
   google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline,"click");
} else {
   geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline.setMap(map);
   google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline,"click");
}
}

function kmlShowPlacemark(pm) {
if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon) {
  map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.bounds);
//show only markers in polygon I zoomed to
for (var i=0;i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
  if   (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(gmarkers[i].getPosition(),geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon)) {
     gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }
 }

 } 


 for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
 var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
 if (i == pm) {
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(null);
   if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);

 } else {
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
   if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(null);
   }
}
}

function kmlColor (kmlIn) {
var kmlColor = {};
if (kmlIn) {
aa = kmlIn.substr(0,2);
bb = kmlIn.substr(2,2);
gg = kmlIn.substr(4,2);
rr = kmlIn.substr(6,2);
kmlColor.color = "#" + rr + gg + bb;
kmlColor.opacity = parseInt(aa,16)/256;
 } else {
// defaults
kmlColor.color = randomColor();
kmlColor.opacity = 0.45;
}
return kmlColor;
}

function randomColor(){ 
var color="#";
var colorNum = Math.random()*8388607.0;  // 8388607 = Math.pow(2,23)-1
var colorStr = colorNum.toString(16);
color += colorStr.substring(0,colorStr.indexOf('.'));
return color;
};

 var highlightOptions = {fillColor: "#b9b8a2", strokeColor: "#000000", fillOpacity: 0.4, strokeWidth: 10};
var highlightLineOptions = {strokeColor: "#000000", strokeWidth: 80};
function kmlHighlightPoly(pm) {
 for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
 var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
 if (i == pm) {
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setOptions(highlightOptions);
   if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setOptions(highlightLineOptions);
 } else {
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setOptions(placemark.polygon.normalStyle);
   if (placemark.polyline)   placemark.polyline.setOptions(placemark.polyline.normalStyle);
 }
 }
 }
function kmlUnHighlightPoly(pm) {
 for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
 if (i == pm) {
   var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setOptions(placemark.polygon.normalStyle);
   if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setOptions(placemark.polyline.normalStyle);
 }
 }
 }


function showAll() {

top.location="test2.php";
map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.bounds); //show all bounds
map.setZoom(13);



//marker.setMap(null); 
for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
 var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
 if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
 if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);
 }
}

function highlightPoly(poly, polynum) {
//    poly.setOptions({fillColor: "#0000FF", strokeColor: "#0000FF", fillOpacity: 0.3}) ;
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseover",function() {
   var rowElem = document.getElementById('row'+polynum);
if (rowElem) rowElem.style.backgroundColor = "#b9b8a2"; //ovo je boja u sidebar-u
if (poly instanceof google.maps.Polygon) {
  poly.setOptions(highlightOptions);
} else if (poly instanceof google.maps.Polyline) {
  poly.setOptions(highlightLineOptions);
}
 });
google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function() {
var rowElem = document.getElementById('row'+polynum);
if (rowElem) rowElem.style.backgroundColor = ""; //pozadina nakon mouserover-a u sidebar-u
poly.setOptions(poly.normalStyle);
});
}  

// == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
function makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i) {
var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name;
 if (!name  || (name.length == 0)) name = "polygon #"+i;
// alert(name);
sidebarHtml += '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td onmouseover="kmlHighlightPoly('+i+');"  onmouseout="kmlUnHighlightPoly('+i+');"><a    href="javascript:kmlPgClick('+i+');">'+name+'</a> - <a  href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+i+');">odaberi</a></td></tr>';

}
function makeSidebarPolylineEntry(i) {
var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name;
if (!name  || (name.length == 0)) name = "polyline #"+i;
// alert(name);
sidebarHtml += '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td onmouseover="kmlHighlightPoly('+i+');"   onmouseout="kmlUnHighlightPoly('+i+');"><a  href="javascript:kmlPlClick('+i+');">'+name+'</a> - <a href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+i+');">show</a></td></tr>';

}


function makeSidebar() {
 sidebarHtml = '<table><tr><td><a href="javascript:showAll();">Prika&#382i sve     kvartove</a></td></tr>';
  var currentBounds = map.getBounds();
 // if bounds not yet available, just use the empty bounds object;
if (!currentBounds) currentBounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
if (geoXmlDoc) {
 for (var i=0; i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {
  if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polygon) {
    if (currentBounds.intersects(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polygon.bounds)) {
      makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i);
    }
  }
 if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polyline) {
  if (currentBounds.intersects(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polyline.bounds)) {
     makeSidebarPolylineEntry(i);
  }
}

}
}
sidebarHtml += "</table>";
 document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
}

function useTheData(doc){
var currentBounds = map.getBounds();
if (!currentBounds) currentBounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
// Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
sidebarHtml = '<table><tr><td><a href="javascript:showAll();">Show All</a></td></tr>';
//  var sidebarHtml = '<table>';
 geoXmlDoc = doc[0];
for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {
// console.log(doc[0].markers[i].title);
var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
if (placemark.polygon) {
  if (currentBounds.intersects(placemark.polygon.bounds)) {
    makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i);
  }
  var kmlStrokeColor = kmlColor(placemark.style.color);
  var kmlFillColor = kmlColor(placemark.style.fillcolor);
  var normalStyle = {
      strokeColor: kmlStrokeColor.color,
      strokeWeight: placemark.style.width,
      strokeOpacity: kmlStrokeColor.opacity,
      fillColor: kmlFillColor.color,
      fillOpacity: kmlFillColor.opacity
      };
  placemark.polygon.normalStyle = normalStyle;

  highlightPoly(placemark.polygon, i);
}
if (placemark.polyline) {
  if (currentBounds.intersects(placemark.polyline.bounds)) {
     makeSidebarPolylineEntry(i);
  }
  var kmlStrokeColor = kmlColor(placemark.style.color);
  var normalStyle = {
      strokeColor: kmlStrokeColor.color,
      strokeWeight: placemark.style.width,
      strokeOpacity: kmlStrokeColor.opacity
      };
  placemark.polyline.normalStyle = normalStyle;

  highlightPoly(placemark.polyline, i);
}


/*    doc[0].markers[i].setVisible(false); */
}
sidebarHtml += "</table>";
document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
};


function hide_kml(){

        geoXml.hideDocument();  

}

function unhide_kml(){

        geoXml.showDocument();  

}
function reload_kml(){
geoXml.hideDocument();
delete geoXml;
geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
                afterParse: useTheData,
                preserveViewport: true
});
geoXml.parse(filename); 

}


 function hide_polys_kml(){
 for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.gpolylines.length;i++) {
   geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[i].setMap(null);
 }
}

function unhide_polys_kml(){
 for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.gpolylines.length;i++) {
   geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[i].setMap(map);
 }
}
 function load_kmlLayer() {
 kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(filename);
 google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, "status_changed", function() {
   document.getElementById('kmlstatus').innerHTML = "Kml Status:"+kmlLayer.getStatus();
 });
 kmlLayer.setMap(map);
}
function hide_kmlLayer() {
 kmlLayer.setMap(null);
}
function show_kmlLayer() {
 kmlLayer.setMap(map);
}

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

    <div id="dmenu">
        <div id="hidden"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle('dmenu');">  <img src="img/x.png"></a></div>
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ODABERI KVART:
            <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
        </div>
            </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to process through the Polygons in your "useTheData" function, which runs after the data is available after processing by geoxml3 and put the number of markers in the infowindow of the clicked polygon.

As you process the array of Placemarks to render the sidebar, also process each polygon to see how many markers it contains:

```
function useTheData(doc){
  var currentBounds = map.getBounds();
  if (!currentBounds) currentBounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
  sidebarHtml = '<table><tr><td><a href="javascript:showAll();">Show All</a></td></tr>';
  geoXmlDoc = doc[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {
    var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
    if (placemark.polygon) { // processing a polygon
      // polygon highlighting
      var kmlStrokeColor = kmlColor(placemark.style.color);
      var kmlFillColor = kmlColor(placemark.style.fillcolor);
      var normalStyle = {
          strokeColor: kmlStrokeColor.color,
          strokeWeight: placemark.style.width,
          strokeOpacity: kmlStrokeColor.opacity,
          fillColor: kmlFillColor.color,
          fillOpacity: kmlFillColor.opacity
          };
      placemark.polygon.normalStyle = normalStyle;

      highlightPoly(placemark.polygon, i);

      // new code  
      var markersInPoly = 0;
      for (var mrkr=0; mrkr<gmarkers.length; mrkr++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(gmarkers[mrkr].getPosition(),placemark.polygon)) {
            markersInPoly++;
        }
      }
      placemark.numMarkers = markersInPoly;
      if (currentBounds.intersects(placemark.polygon.bounds)) {
        makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i);
      }
      clickablePolygon(placemark, "contains "+markersInPoly+" markers"); 
    }
// rest of processing (note if you will never have polylines, you can remove that code).
```

Function to add the number of markers to the polygon's infowindow:

```
function clickablePolygon(placemark, info) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(placemark.polygon, "click", function(e) {
    if (e && e.latLng) {
      infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    } else {
      infowindow.setPosition(placemark.polygon.bounds.getCenter());
    }
    infowindow.setContent('<div class="geoxml3_infowindow"><h3>' + placemark.name +
               '</h3><div>' + info + '</div></div>');
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

[working proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mini_hr_stanonline_test_mouseover_20130314.html)