# a href in a infowindow maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, declaration, infowindow

It's possible to call *JavaScript* from link in a *infowindow*? Know it's possible but in my case I can't figure how to declare *i* ?

i is a polygon number, and it mean to call *function kmlShowPlacemark(i)*

Here's my example:

```
function clickablePolygon(placemark, info, i) {
     var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name;
     var numMkrs = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].numMarkers;
     google.maps.event.addListener(placemark.polygon, "click", function(e) {
        if (e && e.latLng) {
             infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
        } else {
             infowindow.setPosition(placemark.polygon.bounds.getCenter());
        }
    infowindow.setContent('<div class="geoxml3_infowindow"><h3>' + placemark.name +
           '</h3><div>' + info + '<br><a href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+ i + ');">Show place</a></div>');
        infowindow.open(map); 
     });
}
```

Comment: It is possible. We need more context.

Comment: I looked at your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415357/marker-cluster-number-in-a-polygon-or-and-infowindow) where I wrote this code for you.  How are you calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, looks like your HTML in the InfoWindow is invalid (that is the only real difference I see):

```
function clickablePolygon(placemark, info, i) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(placemark.polygon, "click", function(e) {
    if (e && e.latLng) {
      infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    } else {
      infowindow.setPosition(placemark.polygon.bounds.getCenter());
    }
    infowindow.setContent('<div class="geoxml3_infowindow"><h3>' + placemark.name +
               '</h3><div>' + info + '</div>'+'<br><a href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+ i + ');">Show place</a></div>');
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

[modified proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mini_hr_stanonline_test_mouseover_20130319.html)

Comment: It work good only think is that infowindow is not auto closed when javascript is called [example](http://mini.hr/stanonline/test2.php)

Comment: So write code to close it.  I would think infowindow.close() in kmlShowPlacemark should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

**Replace:**

```
<a href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+ i + ');">Show place</a>
```

**With**

```
<a href="#" onclick="kmlShowPlacemark('+ i + '); return false;">Show place</a>
```

Comment: still problem with opening infowindow, think is a problem in declaration of i with var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name; ?

Comment: I noticed you are missing a closing </div> but am not sure that will solve the problem. Are you saying the infowindow does not open at all?

Comment: Yes, it does not open at all, when comment is made for `//var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name; //var numMkrs = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].numMarkers;` it open but without function for _Show place_ link

Comment: Does the JavaScript console show any errors? Are you able to debug and step through the code.If so, what is the value of "i" and "name"?

Comment: Error _Uncaught_ _TypeError:_ _Cannot_ _read property_ _'name'_ _of_ _undefined_

Comment: Where is geoXmlDoc defined?