# Google Maps - how to get count # of results within a specific boundary?

Tags: google-maps

I'm somewhat familiar with Google Maps API, but I don't know how to approach this problem:

I need to count the number of search results matching a particular query, within a defined boundary. For example, "How many auto repair shops are in Suffolk County, NY, and how many auto repair shops are in Kings County, NY?"

If anyone could explain how to do this using Google Maps API, Fusion Tables, or other free tools, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have the boundary polygon?  Do you have the data to be checked (to see if it is in the boundary)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker cluster number in a polygon or/and infowindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415357/marker-cluster-number-in-a-polygon-or-and-infowindow)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Places Libaray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). It is designed to answer questions like "What is near here?". Here is the list of establishment types that can be searched for: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types